# How to display message in chrome extension on the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm developing chrome extension.

And I want to display message (or popup) to reminder user, to create message I used

```
chrome.notifications.create
```

But message display on bottom right corner , I want message display on top right corner (under extension icon)

so how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

`chrome.notifications` and HTML5 Web Notifications use the chrome notifications center to show notifications to users and there is no way to change where they appear on your screen.

What you can do though is creating a [Chrome App Window](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps) that you can fully customize and set its position whereever you want.
See TimeDoser for example at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/timedoser/cmkneeaihlcdllananjlkmppnkdahdcc?hl=en

[image]

One thing you have to know though is that Chrome Apps are not the same as Chrome Extensions and may not have access to some chrome extension APIs such as browsing data, page action, etc.